# Can't change 'userModel' using AuthComponent in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I'va been trying to change the 'userModel' from the default 'user' to 'usuario'. I'va done this before in CakePHP 1.3 but I can't get it to work using the lastest version.

Here's my code (AppController.php):

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginError' => "Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos.",
            'authError' => "Debes ingresar con tu cuenta de usuario.",
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'administrador', 'action' => 'productos'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'usuarios', 'action' => 'login')
        ),
        'Session',
        'Email'
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            'Basic' => array('userModel' => 'Usuario'),
            'Form' => array('userModel' => 'Usuario')
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The component redirects me to "/users/login" instead of "/usuarios/login" and the login form in "/usuarios/login" doesn't work. It's like I never changed the userModel.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: The component redirects me to "/users/login" instead of "/usuarios/login" and the login form in "/usuarios/login" doesn't work. It's like I never changed the userModel.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this while initializing the Auth Component

In you AppController:

```
public $components = array(
'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'Usuario',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I just tried that but it isn't working. I also tried the beforeFilter() version of what you suggested. Cake keeps redirecting me to "/users/login".

Answer (score 1):

Set custom `UserModel` is nothing to do with `Auth::loginAction` which is point to `/users/login` by default. You can override it in `Controller::beforeFilter()` callback or `Controller::$components` array. Hope help.

Answer (score 0):

Change you `$components` array to this:

```
 public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginError' => "Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos.",
        'authError' => "Debes ingresar con tu cuenta de usuario.",
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'administrador', 'action' => 'productos'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'usuarios', 'action' => 'login'),
        'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'usuario','action' => 'login','plugin' => null),
        'authenticate' => array('Form' => array('userModel' => 'Usuario')

        ),
    ),
    'Session',
    'Email'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginError' => "Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos.",
            'authError' => "Debes ingresar con tu cuenta de usuario.",
            'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'aucusers','action' => 'login'),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'administrador', 'action' => 'productos'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'usuarios', 'action' => 'login')
        ),
        'Session',
        'Email'
        );
   }
```

i hv added this the folowing line

```
'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'aucusers','action' => 'login'),
```