# Modifying userModel is totally ignored in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I've tried all the possible combination for modifying the default model for authentication in cakephp 2.5

actually my current appController is

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'utente',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            )
        )
    );    

    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->fields = array(
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            );
        $this->Auth->userModel = 'Utente';
    }
}
```

I have also tried with [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929129/cakephp-authentication-component-using-a-different-table-name-and-column-name) but going into /cakephp-master/ redirect me with no regret to users/login. why?

Comment: Also not working:$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'Utente'
        )
);

Comment: Exactly the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980196/cant-change-usermodel-using-authcomponent-in-cakephp

Comment: Solved with loginAction' => array('controller' => 'utente', 'action' => 'login')

Comment: please write an answer or delete the question. A comment saying "solved xxx" doesn't make the site treat the question as answered.